# Apple Studio Display DP/USB speed is a mystery

Tags: usb, displayport

There is an iPad [footnote](https://www.apple.com/ca/studio-display/specs/#footnote-2):

> When connected to iPad Pro 12.9-inch (3rd and 4th generation), iPad Pro 11-inch (1st and 2nd generation) or iPad Air (5th generation), Studio Display USB-C ports deliver USB 2 data transfer speeds.

1. 5120 x 2880 @ 60Hz 10bit needs [27.72 Gbit/s](https://linustechtips.com/topic/729232-guide-to-display-cables-adapters-v2/?section=calc&H=5120&V=2880&F=60&bpc=10&calculations=show&formulas=show) display bandwidth.
2. These devices do not have Thunderbolt support. Thus, the only way this much display bandwidth could be achieved would be using VESA DSC.
3. DSC is defined with 3:1 compression and then the bandwidth need is 9.24 gbit/s. Even at 2.5:1 we are looking at less than **11.1 gbit/s**.
4. There's a USB C mode defined where two lanes are used for DisplayPort and the remaining two lanes are used for USB traffic, the so called DP Alt Mode with Multi-function suppport (5.2.3.1 of the USB4 standard - I myself have fixed a [bug](https://superuser.com/a/1536688/41259) in this section), often abbreviated as MFDP. Two lanes of DisplayPort using HBR3 have **12.96 gbit/s** display bandwidth. (If DSC support is present so must be HBR3 because HBR3 was defined in DisplayPort 1.3 while DSC was defined in DisplayPort 1.4.)

I am reasonably confident if Apple could've delivered higher than USB 2.0 speed they would've done so. Therefore we can only conclude my assumptions above are wrong. But where?

Ps. a really interesting proposal was it uses XPC or some other Apple proprietary protocol but it [works with Windows PCs](https://www.theverge.com/2022/3/9/22969789/apple-studio-display-windows-pc-compatibility-camera-5k-thunderbolt).